# Multivariable function as a set of functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. I've understood that it can be seen as: $f_i = (f_1,f_2,\ldots ,f_m)$, where $f_i: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$.

What are $f_i$ exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're thinking of a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Wait, let me correct something.

Comment: I have actually understood it. Should I erase this question?

Comment: @jmiller You don't have to delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n$, we have that $f(x)$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^m$. Hence it has $m$-components, which we call $f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x)$, i.e.
$$f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x))\in\Bbb R^m.$$
Each $f_i$ then gives a number in $\Bbb R$ for each $x\in\Bbb R^n$, that is
$$f_i:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1):

Those $f_i$ are the $m$ component functions into which $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ can be decomposed.

If $e_i$ is a canonical base vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$, we have
$$
f(x) = \sum_i f_i(x)\, e_i \quad f_i(x) = f(x) \cdot e_i
$$